Making the JIT compiler eliminate bounds checking with 'arraygleton' classes in C# 8 and earlier
In my project most of the classes (and especially the kind that contains a lot of data) are of the form:
public class Polygon
{
    ////////// Static //////////

    public static readonly Polygon[] Items;

    ////////// Constructor //////////

    public readonly int Index;   
    public readonly Ring[] Rings; // [0, 1+[ 0 : Outer ring, 1+ : Inner ring.

    ...
    
    public Polygon(int index, Ring[] rings) { ... }

    ////////// NOT Constructor (but init-only) //////////

    public MultiPolygon MultiPolygon;

    ...
}

Which is what I call 'arraygletons'. Such are also its supra-class 'Ring' and its super-class 'MultiPolygon'. All 'Polygon' instances are created at the same time, none is ever discarded and Polygon.Items is populated only once with all said instances.
I know the JIT compiler eliminates bounds checking in many simple cases in C# making the use of pointers and unsafe code often redondant. How can I make sure it does eliminate bounds checking when accessing Class.Items each and every single time without having myself to rewrite it all with pointers?
I'm using C# 8 with only some features of C#9 and I can't use the 'init' keyword. (Not sure if it would be a solution.)
